# how do I disable piping aws help to the pager?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I run `aws command help` it pipes the output through the pager. It has it's pros and cons; the biggest con is that once I press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit, everything is gone from the screen (yes, I know, I can crash it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).

Is there a way to *just* output it to the screen the way it works in Windows command prompt? With `man` I can run it as `man -P cat mv`, but I couldn't find anything like that in aws help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple options.

1. Add an alias to your .profile or .bash_profile script (depends on which you are using)

   `alias man='man -P cat'`
2. Change the default pager. (Can be added to you profile as above).

   `export PAGER=cat`

Comment: the first one doesn't work (apparently, aws ignores the value of `man` alias, which is not surprising). However, the second options works great! Thank you